# Unit Test Firebase Dynamic Link onLink behaviour for Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, unit-testing, firebase-dynamic-links

I use firebase dynamic link in my flutter app.
The handler for the onLink behaviour looks like the following:

```
    Future<void> _initDynamicLinking({
    required Emitter<LoginBaseState> emit,
  }) async {
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
        onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData? dynamicLink) async {
      final Uri? link = dynamicLink?.link;

      if (deepLink != null) {
        await _someLogic(link, emit);
      }
    }, onError: (OnLinkErrorException e) async {
      print(e.message);
    });

    final PendingDynamicLinkData? data =
        await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    final Uri? link = data?.link;

    if (deepLink != null) {
      await _someLogic(link, emit);
    }
  }
```

Is it possible to write a unit test to cover the `_someLogic` case?
How can I mock the Dynamic Link behaviour in the test?

Thanks for any help!